# XML Node Value with Attribute

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to retrieve a value from an XML node with an attribute using JavaScript. Here is an XML snippet.

```
<p:Header>
    <p:DocID>
        <p:ID>1234</p:ID>
    </p:DocID>
    <p:QualTerm type="SomeType">
        <p:ID schemeName="SomeScheme">5678</p:ID>
    </p:QualTerm>
</p:Header>
```

Here is a JavaScript snippet.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/rest/getsomedata",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    data: id,
    dataType: "xml",
    cache: false,
    success: [
        function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var node1 = data.getElementsByTagName("p:Header");
            var id = data.getElementsByTagName("p:ID");

            for (var outerIndex = 0; outerIndex < node1.outerIndex; index ++) {
                for (var innerIndex = 0; innerIndex < id.length; innerIndex ++) {
                    var tag = data.getElementsByTagName("p:ID")[innerIndex];
                    var child = tag.childNodes[innerIndex];
                    var value = child.nodeValue;
                    alert(value);
                }
            }

            $("#footerMessage").find("span").remove();
            $("<span>Success! Data retrieved.</span>").appendTo("#footerMessage");
            console.log("Success! Data requested: " + data);
        }
    ]
```

I can retrieve the value of the first p:ID node just fine but the second time through the inner loop I receive an "undefined" value for for the second p:ID that has an attribute. How do I pull the actual value, 5678, from that second p:ID node? Thanks a bunch in advance for any assistance.

Comment: This is [tag:xsl] syntax you have there, and it's most likely to respond with errors. Why don't you use regular [tag:xml] tags like `<p id="1234">` or `<p><id>1234</id></p>`? [tag:xsl] is used to create [tag:xml] templates.

Comment: That snip is from an XML document that is provided to me. I guess I could make edits to it but I would rather not if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in this line here:

```
var child = tag.childNodes[innerIndex];
```

You always need to get the first child node of `<p:ID>` tag which contains the text ID, so, you'll always have to get it using this code:

```
var child = tag.childNodes[0];
```

It works for the fist element, because the first element is actually of `0` index.

Comment: Thank you, Christos. I can't believe I missed that. One little nugget can take a long time to figure out. Anyhow, thanks again.